# Cannot convert value of type 'URL?' to expected argument type 'String'

Tags: swift, database, string, image, url

I am attempting to upload image data to my Firebase database, but cannot convert the image URLs into String for storage. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

```
    @IBAction func shareButton_TouchUpInside(_ sender: Any) {
        ProgressHUD.show("Waiting...", interaction: false)
        if let profileImg = self.selectedImage, let imageData = profileImg.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.1) {
            let photoIdString = NSUUID().uuidString
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: Config.STORAGE_ROOF_REF).child("posts").child(photoIdString)
            storageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil, completion: {(metadata, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    ProgressHUD.showError(error!.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }
                let photoUrl = storageRef.downloadURL(completion: {url, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        print("Failed to download url:", error!)
                        return
                    } else {
                        self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url)
                    }
                })
            })
        } else {
            ProgressHUD.showError("Image Cannot be Empty")
        }
    }
```

Comment: `url.absoluteString`

Comment: That fixed it thanks for your time!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change

```
self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url)
```

to

```
self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url!.absolutString)
```

`url` is of type `URL?` than can't be sent to method that accepts `String`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the Instance Property `absoluteString`  in order
to retrieve the URL string.

Change

```
self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url)
```

to

```
guard let url = url else {return}
self.sendDatatoDatabase(photoUrl: url.absoluteString)
```

it will make you avoid to force unwrap